# Multiple tables for many-to-many mappings or one table with multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql, schema, many-to-many

I'm using Postgres 14 and I have a `tags` table with a many-to-many relationship with other entities such as posts, comments, pages, etc. I've currently been representing these with tables like `posts__tags` which have `id, tag_id, post_id`. It seems easier to just have one table like `tagged_entities` with columns `id, tag_id, post_id, comment_id, page_id, ...`. What are the reasons not to take this approach? It would simplify the associated application entities and logic and require less work as new taggable entities are added. As I understand it, the pros and cons are:

**Table-per-mapping**

*Pros*

- Each row has only three columns, each of which is non-null

*Cons*

- Adds table "bloat"
- Extra effort to add new mappings

**Single table**

*Pros*

- Conceptually simpler
- Less effort to maintain and add new mappings

*Cons*

- More space taken up by each row

Is there anything else I'm missing? Every column would be indexed in the single-table approach, but if null values aren't included in an index, I wouldn't expect the performance due to indexing to be any different.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, those are good points!

Answer (score 2):

Your list of Pros and Cons need further refinement

**Table-per-mapping**

This does not need an `id` column, you can create a primary key across the other two.

Pros

- Each row has only <strike>three</strike> ***two*** columns, each of which is non-null
- *No need to take the existing table offline for changes, or to modify every existing row.*

Cons

- Adds table "bloat" — *yes, but reduces column bloat*
- <strike>Extra effort to add new mappings</strike> — *not really, see below*

**Single table**

This is going to need a complex `CHECK` constraints which will need to be updated for each new column, of the form:

```sql
CHECK ((
    CASE WHEN post_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
    CASE WHEN comment_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
    CASE WHEN page_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  ) = 1
)
```

Pros

- Conceptually simpler — *is it? It's going to be a confusing table to query, with a lot of column bloat.*
- <strike>Less effort to maintain and add new mappings</strike> — *given the effort involved in changing the `CHECK` and adding extra indexes on alive table, probably not.*

Cons

- <strike>More space taken up by each row</strike> — *No, because null values don't take space, unless you have a lot.*
- *Each combination of columns requires a separate index, effectively duplicating the table so it becomes the equivalent of Table-per-Mapping.*
- *Requires taking the table offline for changes, and every existing row needs to be modified.*
- *Does not meet proper normalization standards.*

---

**All-in-all, sounds like the first option is much better.** All you would need to add a new mapping to an entity named `x` is

```sql
CREATE TABLE tag_x (
    tag_id bigint REFERENCES tag (tag_id),
    x_id bigint   REFERENCES x   (x_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, x_id),
    UNIQUE (x_id, tag_id)
);
```

Whereas for the other option, you would need to add the column and foreign key, but also modify the `CHECK` constraint and add indexes, and probably do this during a maintenance window.